# Errors while using MaskedEditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to use MaskedEditText for the phone number.
This is the xml code:

```
 <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Phone number"
    app:met_mask="+## (###) ### ## ##"
android:maxLength="13"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    />''
```

What I added to grade:

```
implementation 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'
```

And the errors are:

`error: attribute met_mask (aka com.example.app2:met_mask) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.`

Please help me!

Comment: The library uses the property `mask` instead of `met_mask`: https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask#user-content-usage. It would make sense with your error. Is that better using the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the library which you are using https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask,

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
android:id="@+id/phone_input"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="phone"
android:typeface="monospace"
mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
mask:mask="+7(###)###-##-##"
android:hint="1234567890"
app:keep_hint="true"
/>
```

You are using the property:

```
app:met_mask="+## (###) ### ## ##"
```

but library allows:

```
  mask:mask="+7(###)###-##-##"
```

So, please use it accordingly as it is specified.

Hope it will work!!!